# How to move from one fragment to another fragment on click of an ImageView in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have an ImageView. I want to move from one fragment to another fragment on a click of an Imageview, the same way like we can move from one activity to another using

```
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

How can I do this? Can anyone explain to me step by step?

My codes are as follows:

**mycontacts.class**

```
public class mycontacts extends Fragment {
    public mycontacts() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ImageView purple=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        purple.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //how to go to tasks fragment from here???
            }
        });
        return view;

    } 
}
```

**tasks.class**

```
public class tasks extends Fragment {
    public tasks() { 
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_one, container,
            false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
purple.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Fragment fragment = new tasks();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
});
```

You write the above code...there we are replacing R.id.content_frame with our fragment.

Comment: Fragment fragment=new tasks(); I am getting error `cannot convert fragments to task`. What to do?

Comment: tasks extends fragment...so tasks is subclass of fragment only and make sure your import statements

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

if still errors then post your log messages

Comment: tasks fragment has the layout id `r.id.task`. and my current fragment has layout id `r.id.contact`. so what should i write inplace of `r.id.content_frame`?

Comment: ok..you are now in MyContacts fragment na....how do you start that...?check that ..you might call to mycontacts fragment from somewhere by replacing a view....so here also you have to mention the same view ..
hope this helps you.

Comment: Oh, how long I searched for the answer! Thank you! At first, though, the name of the variable tasks (?!) baffled. Then he casually remarked that he called his fragment tasks ! =)

Comment: It works thanks, but how I can also change the selected item on the bar not only the view?

Comment: I got it nvm:
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id./*id of nav bar*/);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id./*id of menu item to be highlighted*/);

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    notification = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.notification);

    notification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fr.replace(R.id.container,new NotificationFragment());
            fr.commit();
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this code where you want to click and load **Fragment**.

```
Fragment fragment = new yourfragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 3):

When you are inside an activity and need to go to a fragment use below

`getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.*TO_BE_REPLACED_LAYOUT_ID*, new tasks()).commit();`

But when you are inside a fragment and need to go to a fragment then just add a `getActivity().` before, so it would become

`getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.*TO_BE_REPLACED_LAYOUT_ID*, new tasks()).commit();`

as simple as that.

The `*TO_BE_REPLACED_LAYOUT_ID*` can be the entire page of activity or a part of it, just make sure to put an id to the layout to be replaced. It is general practice to put the replaceable layout in a `FrameLayout` .

Answer (score 1):

You can move to another fragment by using the FragmentManager transactions. Fragment can not be called like activities,. Fragments exists on the existence of activities.

You can call another fragment by writing the code below:

```
FragmentTransaction t = this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment mFrag = new MyFragment();
t.replace(R.id.content_frame, mFrag);
t.commit();
```

here "R.id.content_frame" is the id of the layout on which you want to replace the fragment.

You can also add the other fragment incase of replace.

Comment: Fragment fragment=new tasks(); I am getting error cannot convert fragments to task. What to do? –

Comment: please check for the imports, Either use supportedFragment or Fragments

Comment: asks fragment has the layout id r.id.task. and my current fragment has layout id r.id.contact. so what should i write inplace of r.id.content_frame?

Answer (score 1):

inside your onClickListener.onClick, put

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new tasks()).commit();
```

In another word, in your mycontacts.class

```
public class mycontacts extends Fragment {

    public mycontacts() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ImageView purple = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        purple.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, new tasks())
                        .commit();
            }
        });
        return view;

    }
}
```

now, remember `R.id.container` is the container (FrameLayout or other layouts) for the activity that calls the fragment

Answer (score 1):

in kotlin, put inside of your current running fragment button.setOnClickListener

```
    val bpfragment = TwoFragment()
    activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.fragment_container, bpfragment)?.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the **Kotlin version** of the above code, you can do it in this way, and **you call replaceFragment(RequiredFragment()) at onClickListener** or wherever you want.

```
private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
val transaction = activity!!.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
transaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment)
transaction.commit()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fl_fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            val fragment = YourFragment3()
            val fm : FragmentManager= requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
            val ft: FragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction()
            ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            ft.commit()
            (activity as MainActivity).binding.viewPager.setCurrentItem(2)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).