# how to switch from one fragment to another fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

Hi I have 5 fragments Now first time when I go to `Activity` of that fragments then default First fragment is called,then on first `Fragment` there is a button by clicking that button I go to the second fragment,similarly in Second fragment There is a button and clicking that button I go to the third fragment and so on.

Now My Question is that Current I am on Fifth fragment ,Now I want to go fifth fragment to second fragment,what should I do for this?
Can any one please tell me?

Comment: just replace fragment and add to stack and the popup back as required

Comment: Reffer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212162/how-to-move-from-one-fragment-to-another-fragment-on-click-of-a-imageview-in-and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pop the fragment by name. While adding fragments to the back stack, just give them a name.

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("frag2");
```

Then in fragment5, pop the back stack using the name ie.. `frag2` and include `POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE`

```
    someButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentManager fm = getActivity()
                    .getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.popBackStack ("frag2", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method to add and replace fragment.

```
 public void addReplaceFragment(Fragment fragment, int addOrReplace) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

    switch (addOrReplace) {
        case addFragment:
            transaction.add(R.id.frame_containerforsearchable, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
            break;
        case replaceFragment:
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_containerforsearchable, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

call of fragment is..

```
addReplaceFragment(currencyFragmentWithSearch, replaceFragment);
```

- replaceFragment integer variable
- currencyFragmentWithSearch Fragment instance

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this :)

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().replace(R.id.yourFrameLayout,new Fragment2(),"FRAG2");

OR

Fragment fragment = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRAG2");
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().replace(R.id.yourFrameLayout,,"FRAG2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Fragment fragment = new SecondFragmentName();
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

just small correction to mudit_sen code. It is working, only if you add .beginTransaction. Thank you.

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.FrameLayoutId,new FragmentName()).commit();
```