# Recyclerview only populates after the orientation changes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have 2 fragments, A and B. fragment B contains the recyclerview and it is populated when fragment B is loaded. However, when i press back in fragment B and I go back to fragment A I try to go back to fragment B again but the recyclerview is not populated.

The strange thing is that it does get populated after i change the screen orientation.

How do I populate the recyclerview after going back to fragment B?

Setting adapter in onCreateView of fragment B:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvPlaylists);
   recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
   layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),1);
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
   PlaylistAdapter adapter = new PlaylistAdapter(savedPlaylists);
   recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class PlaylistAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<PlaylistAdapter.ViewHolder> 
{
   private Context mContext;
   private ArrayList<Playlist> mPlaylists;
   private LayoutInflater mInflater;

   public PlaylistAdapter(ArrayList<Playlist> playlists)
   {
       mPlaylists = playlists;
   }

   @Override
   public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
   {
       View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.playlist_recyclerview_item, parent, false);
       return new ViewHolder(v);
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
   {
       Playlist currentPlaylist = mPlaylists.get(position);
       holder.tvName.setText(currentPlaylist.getName());
       holder.btnPlayPlaylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Log.d("btn clicked","mlk");
           }
       });
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount()
   {
       return mPlaylists.size();
   }


   public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
   {
       public TextView tvName;
       public ImageButton btnPlayPlaylist;

       public ViewHolder(View v)
       {
           super(v);
           tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblPlaylistName);
           btnPlayPlaylist = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnPlayPlaylist);
       }

  }
```

Loading Fragment B:

```
public void navigateFromPlaylistFragmentToSavedPlaylistFragment()
{
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_main, new SavedPlaylistFragment()).addToBackStack("navigatefromplaylistfragmenttosavedplaylistfragment")
            .commit();
}
```

Comment: FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.detach(this).attach(this).commit();

try this....

Comment: I'm not sure where I should put this. I'm loading the fragment in my main activity with the replace method and it's loading just fine but the problem is that my recyclerview isn't populated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212162/how-to-move-from-one-fragment-to-another-fragment-on-click-of-a-imageview-in-and

Comment: In what lifecycle method are you setting your adapter? onCreateView, onCreate?

Comment: In onCreateView

Answer (score 0):

You didn't call **`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`** after initializing Adapter and populating data.

Comment: That didn't work. I also have the problem when the data in the recyclerview hasn't changed.