# How to link and image to another xml layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, image

I am new to android and is in need for some little help.I have a xml layout called fragment_home.xml which contains some images.I want to redirect the user to another page(fragment_about_sl.xml) when the user clicks on an image.Please tell me how to do that and where to place the codes.

**fragment_home.xml(layout with the images)**

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/home"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.sloid.destinations.navigationdrawerfragments.homeFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/aboutslbtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/aboutsl"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/toplandmarks"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_about_sl.xml(the  layout that should be redirected once image is clicked)**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/aboutslscrollview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.sloid.destinations.navigationdrawerfragments.aboutSLFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/viewPager"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I also added the java file if its necessary.

**homeFragment.java(java file for fragment_home.xml)**

```
public class homeFragment extends Fragment {


public homeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("Destinations");
}

}
```

**aboutSLFragment.java(java file for fragment_about_sl.xml)**

```
public class aboutSLFragment extends Fragment{

ViewPager viewPager;
LinearLayout sliderDotspanel;
private int dotscount;
private ImageView[] dots;
TextView aboutsltext;
Button readmorebtn;

public aboutSLFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_sl, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView .findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    sliderDotspanel = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.SliderDots);

    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getContext());

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    dotscount = viewPagerAdapter.getCount();
    dots = new ImageView[dotscount];

    for(int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++){

        dots[i] = new ImageView(getContext());
        dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.non_active_dot));

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.setMargins(8, 0, 8, 0);

        sliderDotspanel.addView(dots[i], params);

    }

    dots[0].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            for(int i = 0; i< dotscount; i++){
                dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.non_active_dot));
            }

            dots[position].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    aboutsltext=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.aboutsltext);
    readmorebtn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.readmorebtn);
    readmorebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (readmorebtn.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Read More"))
            {
                aboutsltext.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);//your TextView
                readmorebtn.setText("Read Less");
            }
            else
            {
                aboutsltext.setMaxLines(3);//your TextView
                readmorebtn.setText("Read More");
            }
        }
    });

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("About Sri Lanka");
}
```

code added to change the fragment

```
 rootView.findViewById(R.id.aboutslbtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment fragment = new aboutSLFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.home, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

logcat

```
 30388-30388/com.example.sloid.destinations E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.sloid.destinations, PID: 30388
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sloid.destinations/com.example.sloid.destinations.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2702)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at com.example.sloid.destinations.navigationdrawerfragments.homeFragment.onCreateView(homeFragment.java:30)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3221)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3171)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:192)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:560)
                                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1234)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6329)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to move from one fragment to another fragment on click of a ImageView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212162/how-to-move-from-one-fragment-to-another-fragment-on-click-of-a-imageview-in-and)

Comment: try this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23212245/8089770

Comment: I've added a piece of code but there is an error I can't resolve.The error is that as soon as I add aboutSLFragment to Fragment fragment new aboutSLFragment() it gives and error called unreachable statement making all thee lines in this code underlined in red.Please tell me what should I do?

Comment: make sure import of Fragment used to replace the fragment and in aboutFragment both are support v4 fragments

Comment: I found the error, it was caused by adding the following code after the  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);.Its solved now, but now another error arised, can you check that, i've addedd the logcat

Comment: And also as shown in this main method of the code in this link(http://abhiandroid.com/ui/fragment) there is something called a <frameLayout>.I don't have that in my code.What is that used for and is that the problem causing the error in my case

Comment: Frame layout is the layout in which your all fragment will inflate. It is like a container. you can change things in this container by this code.

Comment: Here in the code in replace you are giving the id is the contaner's id in which you are changing the fragment

Comment: I didn't get you man.Can you explain me that clearly.I changed my fragment chanaging code too(have a look ) but as the logcat says the error is caused by the following line of code.Can you say whats the problem    rootView.findViewById(R.id.aboutslbtn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

Comment: Is aboutslbtn is the id of layout which you are inflating? check the id may be it can not find the id. and first find the reference and then apply on click

Comment: And check is home id is of container which holds fragment1 and now will replace to fragment2

Comment: Hello vishva, aboutslbtn is the id of the image in which if pressed redirects to another fragment and home is the id of the layout which holds that.(see the first code set)Why is the way I implemented it is wrong, please could you correct that.  To explain you clearly I have a fragment layout called fragment_home.xml which has an image with id called aboutslbtn, which on click should redirect to fragment_about_sl.xml. Is the way I implemented the code is wrong,if so can you correct that

Comment: Let me try. Every fragment has one activity which contains them right? So there should be one Activity which contains homeFragment. Now in that activity where this content is should be a frame layout and that is the container. which will have an id. Ok now once again let me clear Activity is having container which holds homeFragment. and now in homeFragment imageview click you will redirect to aboutSLFragment. this will replace in activity container from homeFragment. That replacement code is perfect just that id need to be from activity(Container).

Comment: That is all i know about fragment :D. Hope you got my point or can try tutorial for fragments. See Container is a box in the activity and you have put a paper in the box your homeFragment. now you want to take that paper and put a new one in the same box. then you will need one box and it's id. in which you will perform all this.right now you are taking id of first paper not box :(

Comment: try this https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-fragment-transaction-fragmentmanager-and-backstack.html

Comment: Bit of trail and error solved the case.Thanks Vishva for your utmost support given to me

Comment: Errors solved by me and accepting answer of other one :( :(

Comment: Of course you solved it,But you answered in the comment section, and how to accept comments, there is no correct symbol in comment section, that's why I thanked you specifically

Comment: :D thank for that. I have posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [My comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48885206/how-to-link-and-image-to-another-xml-layout?noredirect=1#comment84775069_48885206)

Reference : [Fragment replace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23212245/8089770)

```
 Fragment fragment = new aboutSLFragment();
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.home, fragment);
 fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Tutorial : https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-fragment-transaction-fragmentmanager-and-backstack.html

Comment: Thank you so much :) Happy coding :)

Comment: Ok thanks vishva for your utmost support, because of you only i was able to solve this question, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just add ids to those images and handle onclick events inside your fragment. You can find the image view using `findViewById(R.id.'yourId');`

And the onClick listener set: `view.setOnClickListener(...);`

Answer (score 0):

You are new in android right, first of all you need to check [Fragment detail](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

As you question you need to `replace` or `add` fragment as @Vishva Dave  said

[Follow this link](http://abhiandroid.com/ui/fragment)

```
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {

// create a FragmentManager
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

// create a FragmentTransaction to begin the transaction and replace the Fragment
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

// replace the FrameLayout with new Fragment
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);

fragmentTransaction.commit(); // save the changes
}
```

Comment: I've added a piece of code but there is an error I can't resolve.The error is that as soon as I add aboutSLFragment to Fragment fragment new aboutSLFragment() it gives and error called unreachable statement making all thee lines in this code underlined in red.Please tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add `android:id="@+id/imageId"` to the `<ImageView ...` in the `xml`, then in your `homefragment` add this code:

```
public class homeFragment extends Fragment {
View rootView;

public homeFragment() {
// Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageId).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        // go to the other fragment using fragmentTransaction
    });
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
//you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments 
different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("Destinations");
    }

}
```